# Highcharts lang with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, highcharts, internationalization, ngx-translate

I'm currently using Angular 4 for my project, and am using ngx-translate (i18n) to enable users to switch languages. These are set in a i18n folder with json files for different languages. I'm also using high charts for a number of graphs and I found out when I checked out their API that they are also using i18n for languages. However, from what I could gather on the API documentation is that I need to use setOptions on HighCharts and specify the translation words there, however, I was wondering if that could be done using the json files I'm currently using for ngx-translate? Or if users are able to switch between languages, how am I supposed to do that with setOptions?

Answer (score 1):

This **demo** shows how to perform `setOptions` dynamically: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/1qLqhtmd/

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  series: [{
    data: [5.5656565, 20]
  }]
});


setTimeout(function (){
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
      decimalPoint: ' and after the dot is '
    }
  });
  chart.redraw();
}, 3000);
```

Notice that `chart.redraw()` is necessary here. If we comment it out the decimal point will be different only in tooltip after 3s (axes labels won't change).

I think that the easiest approach here is to create function that is going to format the JSON fetched from your file to the structure acceptable by `setOptions` (because its argument is JSON too) and use `setOptions` as shown in the example above.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to setOptions dynamically. However, the titles, unity, and labels cannot be set in setOptions since it is global and I have multiple charts per page. Is there a way to change the language for those properties easily?

Comment: See this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/L6pr2dnu/ It shows how to easily access all existing charts (`Highcharts.charts`), check applied options and use function(s) for modifying already rendered chart (e.g. `Chart.update()`, `Series.update()`, `Chart.setTitle()` - these function are described in this part of the **API**: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/classes.list)